# What is the equivalent of " dplyr Mutate " in data.table , R ?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

## Target data table like below :

```
#DT
NO    GROUP   KEY          TYPE  <--- Create this column
12-19  N      1701         INN
10-20  N      1602         INN
13     P      1501John     BANK
14     R      1408Mary     POOL
15     G      1408Peter    PARK
19     K      1408Paul     BANK
25     P      1708         OTHER
36     R      1503         OTHER
```

## Step 1 : Lookup TYPE information from another table with col : KEY

```
DT[,"TYPE":= RefDT[match(DT$KEY,Ref$KEY),2]]

# RefDT like below :

KEY          TYPE
1609TOM      PARK
1501John     BANK
1408Mary     POOL
1408Peter    PARK
1408Paul     BANK
1309Sue      POOL
```

- The rows which doesn't match KEY become NA 

  #

## Step 2 : Create next group information without overwrite step 1 result

*If Col : No contain "-" , TYPE is "INN" .

```
DT[,TYPE:= ifelse(grepl("-",DT$No),"INN",TYPE)]
```

## Step 3 : Mutate the rest of NA rows without overwrite step 1 & 2 result

*If Col : GROUP is "P" or "R" , TYPE is "Other" , Step 1 rule override this rule. Thats why even some rows contain "P" or "R" in Col : GROUP, they\ir TYPE won't change if they have effective KEY .

```
DT <- DT[is.na(TYPE),] %>% mutate(TYPE = ifelse(grepl("P|R",GROUP),"OTHER",TYPE)) %>%
  rbind(DT[!is.na(TYPE),])
```

## What is the equivalent approach of Step 3 in data.table ?

As actual dataset contains 2 Millions rows , i need a faster
methods to achieve this . Welcome for any effective script to
conclude three clumsy scripts for creating only one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are using `data.table`, do a join by 'KEY' with the 'RefDT' assign (`:=` -similar to `mutate`) the 'TYPE' in 'RefDT' to create the 'TYPE' column in 'DT'.  If there are no matches, it will by default be filled with `NA`.  Then do the subsequent assignments by specifying the logical condition in `i` (`grepl("-", NO)` - check for `-` in the "NO" column, check for "P" or "R" in "GROUP" where the "TYPE" is `NA`)

```
setDT(DT)[RefDT, TYPE := TYPE, on = .(KEY)]
DT[grepl("-", NO), TYPE := "INN"
       ][is.na(TYPE) & grepl("P|R", GROUP), TYPE := "OTHER"][]
#      NO GROUP       KEY  TYPE
#1: 12-19     N      1701   INN
#2: 10-20     N      1602   INN
#3:    13     P  1501John  BANK
#4:    14     R  1408Mary  POOL
#5:    15     G 1408Peter  PARK
#6:    19     K  1408Paul  BANK
#7:    25     P      1708 OTHER
#8:    36     R      1503 OTHER
```

#### data

```
DT <- structure(list(NO = c("12-19", "10-20", "13", "14", "15", "19", 
"25", "36"), GROUP = c("N", "N", "P", "R", "G", "K", "P", "R"
), KEY = c("1701", "1602", "1501John", "1408Mary", "1408Peter", 
"1408Paul", "1708", "1503")), .Names = c("NO", "GROUP", "KEY"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")


RefDT <- structure(list(KEY = c("1609TOM", "1501John", "1408Mary", "1408Peter", 
"1408Paul", "1309Sue"), TYPE = c("PARK", "BANK", "POOL", "PARK", 
"BANK", "POOL")), .Names = c("KEY", "TYPE"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```